# Unity script has no IntelliSense when opened in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, solution

I am trying to script a script names `MouseManager.cs` in Visual Studio. All I did until now is to create the script in the script folder and then double - clicked to open it in Visual Studio. When I do, I found out that the IntelliSense is turned off, making it very hard for me to program. I have `Game development with unity` extension installed and enabled and am running Visual studio LTS. The problem seems to be lack of solution / configuration.
[image: Image of the visual studio workspace after opening the file]
One reason that came to mind as of why that happens, is that I  when I first opened the file `Game development with unity` was not installed. But even after I deleted the script and created a new one the problem persisted, indicating that it's not the reason for the problem.

How do I get IntelliSense back?

Comment: Does the IntelliSense work in general? Have you tried [Ctrl] + [Space]?

Comment: @abo When programming regular c# or C in VS it all works fine